# Does "de-perplex" mean to simplify?

Tags: meaning, verbs

Does de-perplex something complex means to simplify it? I think it does.

I didn't create the word de-perplex by myself. It was a word on the [pcmag.com website](https://uk.pcmag.com/chipsets-processors/120095/the-best-cpus#:%7E:text=Let%27s%20de%2Dperplex%20it!). Here is the original text:

> Whether you're upgrading your desktop PC or building a new one, choosing the right processor is the most crucial and complex choice you will make. Let's de-perplex it!

Comment: [*unperplex*](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/unperplex) would be a better word but still it's rarely used.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is about an invented word.

Comment: If you are asking about a word you see on a website, you should include the quote and link to the website.  I've done this for you.

Answer (score 6):

"de-perplex" is not a standard word in English.

However the "de-" prefix is fairly productive, and this means you can create new words by adding "de-", and those words mean "remove", or "do the opposite"

However, when there is an existing word that expresses what you want, you should not create a new one.  In this case "to simplify" already exists.  You should use that, and not create a new word.

The use in the website is "jocular" it is meant to be odd and interesting, rather than normal and clear.

Comment: I didn't create the word de-perplex by myself.it was a word in pcmag.com website.here is the original text: "Whether you're upgrading your desktop PC or building a new one, choosing the right processor is the most crucial and complex choice you will make. Let's de-perplex it!"

Comment: You need to include that information in the question.  The use is "jocular" that means it intended to be odd and funny.

Comment: @SinaR  It should also be noted that "perplex" is more closely a synonym of "confuse" or "bewilder" (rather than "complex"), and so "de-perplex" means something closer to "make-less-confusing" which may-or-may-not equate to "make-simpler".  For example, explaining the logic behind each individual step of a process does not simplify the process in any way - but it should make the process less puzzling.